# github actions how to set different parameter values in yaml file based on env (dev, uat, prd) without using env secrets

Tags: build, environment-variables, github-actions, workflow, cicd

How to set different parameter values in yaml file based on env (dev, uat, prd) without using env secrets?

Can we set values using the `if` condition based on the environment (dev, uat, prd)?

Need to pass the parameter value to the build command.

It works with environment secrets but these are not secrets and I want developers to change it from code when needed.

I have tried to set the parameter `ans` and finally use it in the build command.

```yaml
- name: set parameteres - dev
  if: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} == "dev"
  env:
    ans: 20
  run: |
    echo "Hello $ans"

- name: set parameteres - uat
  if: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} == "uat"
  env:
    ans: 30
  run: |
    echo "Hello $ans"
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event along with custom inputs to solve this?

Comment: Could you please explain this "**I want developers to change it from code when needed**"?

Comment: I am using workflow_dispatch and AWS secrets for each env - dev, uat and prod works well. Developers are able to promote the branch/tag to respective env.

Comment: End goal is to deploy/build a python datapipeline and it has 2 dozen parameters. The parameters can be diff for diff env. Where to store them - github actions workflow file? As developers should be able to see the parameter values, edit them if required. If you are using secrets you cant see the values easily.

Comment: That makes sense. So, what's currently lacking in your solution? From that snippet in your question, looks like it should work already.